# Swift Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

This has been stumping me for a while now. I have a `UISplitViewController` inside a `UITabBarController`. The master view is a TableView. When I click on a cell, I bring up a very basic view controller with just a `UIButton` centered. Here is the code for the view controller:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let pickerC = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerC.delegate = self

        pickerC.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        pickerC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = button as UIView
        pickerC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = (button as UIView).bounds
        pickerC.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any
        self.presentViewController(pickerC, animated: true, completion: nil)//4
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
       self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

If I click cancel or select and image, the picker controller dismisses properly. The problem comes when I click on the back button to return to the TableView, I receive:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <TestViewController: 0x7fb882a72380>.
```

The `TestViewController` is very basic, so why would this be happening?

Comment: When you return to the `tableView`, maybe the `tableView` tried to present this vc again?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This issue occurs if you trying to push new view controller while previous transaction (animation) in progress. So please check your code flow and make the appropriate changes. Check your dismiss and present view animations. You can use property setAnimation to 'YES/NO'resolve this

Set animated:NO,  may be solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for the help. Strangely enough it helped me track down the problem, which was in the UITabBarController's viewDidAppear method, I was missing the line: super.viewDidAppear(animated).

Comment: @MikeWalker simply call `super.viewDidAppear` saved my daaaayyyyyy.

Comment: @MikeWalker you saved my day, i also missed super, thanks

Answer (score 1):

To me this weird issue was occurring due to following line after implementation of UISplitViewController

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
.
.
.
    // splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .PrimaryOverlay
.
.
.
    }
```

By commenting this line in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forget to delete storyboard file. After I removed it, this warning is gone.