# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions with storyboard and adaptive segues

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using storyboard and have the following VCs:

```
UISplitViewController (Master) > UITabbarController > UINavigationController > UITableViewController

UISplitViewController (Detail) > UINavigationController > UIViewController
```

I'd like to show login screen on startup.

I've added following lines:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    window?.rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    if isAuthorized() == false {
        let loginVc = UIStoryboard("Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Loginn") as! LoginVC
        loginVc.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve
        loginVc.modalPresentationStyle = .PageSheet
        svc.presentViewController(loginVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    return true
}
```

While iPad works fine, iPhone shows me message in console:

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for 
>   < MyProj. SplitViewController: 0x7fa4c9525470 >

How should I present login controller to silence that warning?

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061153/swift-unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thatks for the link. I understand where problem comes from, but I can't see how to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the code showing login view controller in the viewdidappear in the mainviewcontroller??

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    let loginVc = UIStoryboard("Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Loginn") as! LoginVC
    loginVc.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve
    loginVc.modalPresentationStyle = .PageSheet
    svc.presentViewController(loginVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: With your approach you just replace rootVC, but not animate it

Comment: So you want to modally show login view controller what ever the situation is??

Comment: I want to show modal LoginVC if user is not authorized